# bower install vs. bower install --save vs. bower install --save-dev, Git doesn't save bower_components directory?

Tags: angularjs, git, bower, gitlab, angular-bootstrap

I was trying to update angular-bootstrap, I ran

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
```

But other devs at the office said to use:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap --save
```

BUT I've also seen:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap --save-dev
```

PROBLEM!

Project didn't work, So I tried a git reset --hard to a commit with a working version:

```
git reset --hard <commit#>
```

BUT that didn't fix it. 
In Gitlab, the bower_components directory wasn't saved to the online repo, but the bower.json file was.

So when should we use:

```
bower install <package>

bower install <package> --save

bower install <package> --save-dev
```

Comment: does bower_components exist in .gitignore?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing bower_components in the .gitignore file.

Also checked my bower_components dir - .bower.json has version 1.3.1;
bower.json file has version 1.3.1 before reload; after Sublime asks to reload, still same:

Main bower.json file in parent dir has "dependencies": {..., "angular-bootstrap": "^1.3.1"}

Comment: git doesn't save the directory because bower_components is configured to be ignored, so what's the issue?

Comment: So when should we use:

bower install <package>

bower install <package> --save

bower install <package> --save-dev

Comment: you use --save to add the package to dependency list in bower.json. If you just run bower install <package>, bower.json won't be updated. It is nothing to do with git.